# Can daily 90VAC shocks have effect on human body?

Tags: mains, grounding, shock

There is external audio card on my desk with gold plated ports. For several years, whenever I accidently touch these with my elbow I would get a little shock, sometimes I would touch the PC case with my leg and get a tickle sensation. This occured on daily basis and I always put the blame on faulty electronics in the sound card. I did not pay too much attention to it.

Today I discovered that this was caused by the ground pin in the outlet being broken, so there was no contact and what I was feeling was leakage through my body to the ground.

I measured the voltage between the case and my body, and it is 90-150 VAC.

Being curious I want to know if there could be some long term effects in such situation. Could this do something to my heart or my brain?

I tried to look for peer reviewed articles, but I am not able to find the right keywords.

Comment: The long term psychological effect seems strong doesn't it?

Comment: @user3528438 One can never recognize it's own insanity.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably feeling small leakage currents from a Y-capacitor connected from the line to chassis.  These are specified so that a dangerous amount of current can't flow if the chassis ground opens up, as it did in your case.

The chance of it having any effect on you is extremely small, but this is an engineering site, not a medical site.  If you have concerns you should be asking your doctor, not random non-medical people on the internet.